# graphicsmagick burst multi page tiff into 2 page tiff's

Tags: tiff, graphicsmagick, multipage

I have a tiff file with several hundred pages in it.  My goal is to break it into many files each containing two pages.  i.e. every two pages save a new file.  It is basically a stack of single sheet documents scanned front and back.

I'm working on a C# Forms (visual studio 2008) application to automate the process.

My initial thought is to use Graphicsmagick to split every page into a seperate file then step through the files to join them back to geather again two pages at a time.

I have the split process working by calling a command like this.

```
gm convert largeinputfile.tif +adjoin singlepageoutput%d.tif
```

When I try and join just two of the pages back togeather again with a command like this

```
gm convert -page A4 -append singlepageoutput0.tif singlepageoutput1.tif New2pageImage.tif
```

This creates one long document containing both pages but no page break.
I have tried seveveral things with the `-page` option but I'm just guessing and it's not having much effect.

I'm very close to a working solution but stuck on the last bit.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance
David

Comment: I hate answering my own questions but I was barking up the wrong tree. :) The answer is 
gm convert -adjoin singlePage0.tif singlePage1.tif newoutput.tif

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would answer this as I had a similar problem and this was the first SO question I came across.

This will take the first two pages and create a new multi-page tiff file.

```
gm convert -page A4 page0.tif page1.tif -adjoin output.tif
```

Then you take the file you have created and add a new page to it.

```
gm convert output.tif page2.tif -adjoin output.tif
gm convert output.tif page3.tif -adjoin output.tif
.... and so on ....
```

This will also have the added benefit of not eating through CPU and RAM as graphics magick will try to do the whole thing in RAM and a 10MB 500 page tiff will take about 24GB of RAM if done in one go.